# Google's Chrome Bookmark Manager Seems to Have Stopped syncing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-bookmarks

I've got a windows 8, windows 10 and macbook (OSX) all with latest chrome installed.  The two windows bookmarks are syncing but the chrome on OSX seems to have stopped.  It was working but not anymore.

I verified they all have the same google account, they all have (under advanced settings) bookmarks checked to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that it is not asking for a secret passphrase? Mine asks for it once in a while to re-enable sync. Check your account settings. If that doesn't work, log out of the account and log back in again. It should fix it.